# Display specific image based on column ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, datagridview

I have an asp.net webform C# with a datagridview. There is a jpg image file for every ID # that is saved as the exact number of the ID field.
Basically what I want to do is find a way to display the image based on the selected rows ID column.  There are hundreds of rows so how can I get it to select the image based on the ID?

For example, I have 3 columns:

```
ID  | FirstName | LastName |
----------------------------
2324| John      | Doe      |
2034| Jane      | Doe      |
2946| Mike      | Blank    |
```

Lets's say Mike Blank is selected. I want to display the image 2946.jpg (because that's what his ID # is) on the top of the page.

Note:All images are saved in the same folder.

Comment: Do you want to display the image next to the DataGridView? In a PictureBox for example? And update the picture when another Row has been clicked? Nevertheless the answer of C. Helling should provide all information necessary to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will insert an image column at index 0, grab the image stored in `C:\Images\[userID].jpg`, and it will load them on cell click. The general idea remains the same, you need to add a `DataGridViewImageColumn`, which you can then populate however or whenever you'd like.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.usersTableAdapter.Fill(this.testDBDataSet.Users);
    DataGridViewImageColumn imageCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, imageCol);
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Image";
}

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int userID = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(@"C:\Images\" + userID + ".jpg");    
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = img;
}
```

It produces output like so:

[image: WinForm with Image column]

To add an image somewhere else in the form, you need to create a `PictureBox` to your form, and on the row click (or whenever you want to update the image), simply set e.g.

```
int userID = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"C:\Images\" + userID + ".jpg";
```

Comment: Maybe I was unclear.  The images are already saved in a folder c\images with the names of the ID column.  So on the webform, if a user selects a certain row in the datagrid, I want to display the image associated with the ID column.  Does that make sense?

Comment: If you mean replace the "ID" cell itself with an image, that would be particularly difficult, especially since you can't alter the column type after it is bound to a data source. I create a `DataGridViewImageColumn` which I then inserted images into. I insert the image on cell click, but you populate the column however you'd like. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: This is what i'm going for but I don't want the image to be displayed in a column in the gridview.  I would like it to be displayed on top of the page.  So when whenever a row is selected it will display the associated image on top of the page.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your question, I got hung up on the "column ID" part. If you want to add an image somewhere else, you will need to add a `PictureBox` component to your form at the top of the page, and you can then set the image source for that picture box on your row select event. Please let me know if you encounter further issues.