# Print image from DataGridview?

Tags: c#, .net, image, datagridview

I need to show picture from dataGrid to print Page? How do I set a value image?

```
private void printDocument_nahlad_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   //e.Graphics.DrawImage(dataGridView_nahlad.Rows[0].Cells[12]........... = , 620, 55, 120, 120);
}
```

[image]

I added code , where save picture to database SQL. Create a QRcode that save as a picture.I show  all code to save data.

Create new :

```
public partial class form : Form
{

    kasspoxTestEntities test;

        private void btn_novy_vystup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            panel_vystup.Enabled = true;
            cmb_dodavatel_vystup.Focus();

            tab_vystup f = new tab_vystup();
            test.tab_vystup.Add(f);
            tabvystupBindingSource.Add(f);
            tabvystupBindingSource.MoveLast();

        }


          private void btn_generovat_vystup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_dodavatel_vystup.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_cislo_palety_vystup.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_hrubka_vystup.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_sirka_vystup.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_dlzka_vystup.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_pocet_vystup.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_kvalita_vystup.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_druh_vystup.Text))
        {


                txt_objem_vystup.Text = (((Convert.ToInt32(txt_hrubka_vystup.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(txt_sirka_vystup.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(txt_dlzka_vystup.Text) * 0.000000001) * Convert.ToInt32(txt_pocet_vystup.Text)).ToString());
                txt_objem_vystup.Text = Math.Round(double.Parse(txt_objem_vystup.Text), 3).ToString();

                MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder encoder = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder();
                encoder.QRCodeScale = 8;

                Bitmap bmp = encoder.Encode(cmb_dodavatel_vystup.Text + ";" +
                                                txt_cislo_palety_vystup.Text + txt_datum_vystup.Text + txt_smena_vystup.Text + ";" +
                                                txt_hrubka_vystup.Text + txt_sirka_vystup.Text + txt_dlzka_vystup.Text + ";" +
                                                txt_pocet_vystup.Text + ";" +
                                                cmb_kvalita_vystup.Text + ";" +
                                                txt_objem_vystup.Text + ";" +
                                                cmb_druh_vystup.Text);



                txt_link.Text = (cmb_dodavatel_vystup.Text + ";" +
                                                txt_cislo_palety_vystup.Text + txt_datum_vystup.Text + txt_smena_vystup.Text + ";" +
                                                txt_hrubka_vystup.Text + txt_sirka_vystup.Text + txt_dlzka_vystup.Text + ";" +
                                                txt_pocet_vystup.Text + ";" +
                                                cmb_kvalita_vystup.Text + ";" +
                                                txt_objem_vystup.Text + ";" +
                                                cmb_druh_vystup.Text);


                pictureBox.Image = bmp;
                btn_tlacit_vystup.Enabled = true;
                lb_pozor.Visible = false;

                 MessageBox.Show("Kód bol vygenerovaný a paleta uložená", "Informácia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                tabvystupBindingSource.EndEdit();
                tabskladBindingSource.EndEdit();
                test.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Can you clarify the issue? You're printing a page of your DataGridView with an image column, the image is visible in the data grod, but no image shows up when you print?

Comment: I added a picture. Yes the picture is visible in dagrid and I want print .

Comment: In text example: e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Rows[i].Cells[11].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(350, height + 80));

Comment: But the picture I do not know @C.Helling

Comment: `pictureBox.Image = bmp` -- so here this is a bitmap that you save in a picture box, but how is it saved in the column? What is the DataGridViewCell type of your column "QRCODE"? I am thinking that it is actually a byte array on your DataGridView and not a Bitmap.

Comment: @C.Helling you can send me mail, I'll send you the entire code.(matus.kasper(at)gmail.com)

Answer (score 0):

So, I started with my [previous example WinForm with an image column.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124994/display-specific-image-based-on-column-id/42125539#42125539) (You might need to view the edit history to view how I originally added the image column).

The next step is to go to your Toolbox, and add "PrintDocument" to your form (under "Printing"). It will show up on the bottom of your screen, and right click > view Properties. In the Properties window, click the thunderbolt icon to bring up events, and double click the field for "PrintPage". This creates a PrintPage event. Use the following code:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height);
            dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
        }
```

You can also add a print button for convenience, e.g.:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog.Document = printDocument1;
        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }
```

This will convert your DataGridView to an image, which will then print. I tested it in my form, and it printed the image column just fine.

Alternatively, you can view some sample CodeProjects [here](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/printing/dgvprinter.aspx) and [here.](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/28046/printing-of-datagridview)

**Edit based on OP's comments:** If you want to pass a specific image to the printer, you can either find a way to pass your image location to a Bitmap constructor (e.g. `Bitmap(imageLocation)`) or you can take the Bitmap directly from the DataGridViewImageColumn, like so:

```
printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // figure out how you're selecting an image
    // this selects the highlighted row
    int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    // select the image column
    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);     
}
```

Comment: It´s good, but i want print one cell with image ,no whole table.

Comment: I updated my answer. It would have been a lot easier with sample code, because there are multiple ways to do what you're asking, but the idea remains the same: get the System.Drawing.Bitmap object, and call `e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0)` in the `printDocument_PrintPage` function. Seeing how you currently implemented it would have made it easier to fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void printDocument_nahlad_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

            // prvy štitok
            // prvy stlpec
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Columns[0].HeaderText.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(75,55));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Rows[0].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(150, 55));

            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(75, 75));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Rows[0].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(150, 75));

            // druhy stlpec

            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Columns[5].HeaderText.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(290, 55));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Rows[0].Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(350, 55));

            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Columns[6].HeaderText.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(290, 75));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Rows[0].Cells[6].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(350, 75));


            // treti stlpec

            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Columns[9].HeaderText.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(450, 55));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Rows[0].Cells[9].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(520, 55));

            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Columns[10].HeaderText.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(450, 75));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Rows[0].Cells[10].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(520, 75));

            // vykreslenie čiar

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen (Brushes.Black, 3), 75 ,190,740,190);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3), 75, 45, 740, 45);


            //CODE FOR MY IMAGE

           // Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)dataGridView_nahlad.Rows[0].Cells[12].Value;
            //e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 620, 55, 120, 120);

       }
```

Comment: Did my code not fix your issue? And if not, can you please tell me specifically what the issue is?

Comment: Your error is an invalid cast. Can you please show me the code where you insert the image data into the DataGridView? I cannot possibly tell you why you're getting an invalid cast when I don't know what you're casting from. Also, please edit your question to include additional information, instead of posting it as a new "answer."